js element.click() on focusable element does not shift focus to that element
I stumbled across this behaviour. I want that an input element receives focus, if you click it, so that it becomes the documents' active element. The click is generated programmatically via javascript with element.click(). A default action for focusable elements is, that they receive focus, if clicked w3.


const e = document.getElementById("dom-root");
const e2 = document.createElement("input");
e.appendChild(e2);

e2.addEventListener("click", () => e2.focus());

console.log("Before click:", document.activeElement);
e2.click();
console.log("After click:", document.activeElement);
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="dom-root"></div>
  </body>
</html>



The focus does not change. I tested this with Chrome and Safari.
According to this page Most untrusted events will not trigger default actions, with the exception of the click event. This event always triggers the default action, even if the isTrusted attribute is false So I would expect that the focus is changed.
Why isn't the focus changed?

There's a difference between a real "click" (a user input action) and the programmatic triggering of the event.

"they receive focus, if clicked" - but you're not clicking it, you're firing the event handler for the click event.

I know of the difference between real and programmatic clicks. However, the w3 documents says that click will always generate default actions. And shifting focus, if the element is focusable is one. Is there any documentation, that my observed behaviour is the intended one?

"w3 documents says that click will always generate default actions" - the w3 doc you linked to uses "click" to mean "click of the mouse".

The W3 DOM spec is about what the browser is supposed to do with a page of HTML. It is generally not about JavaScript behavior at all.

w3 specifies what to do on a click event, not where it came from. And the mozilla docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click say that the click-method fires a click-event.

I suspect you're looking the wrong place.  Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click (MDN)   "The HTMLElement.click() method simulates a mouse click on an element. When called on an element, the element's click event is fired (unless its disabled attribute is set)."  - doesn't state the elements default action.  They're not the same thing.

@fdomn-m Sorry I kind of copied your comment, I didn't see it until after

@Mippy no worries - comments don't count as answers, so are free-game.  Doesn't look like you copied, just came to the same conclusion (gave you a +1)

From Mozilla's web documentation:

The HTMLElement.click() method simulates a mouse click on an element. When called on an element, the element's click event is fired (unless its disabled attribute is set).

It does not focus the element because it is "simulating" a click, not an actual click.  Just use .focus() on an element you need to focus.

In addition, there's a whole bunch of properties that the click event provides, which are not provided by the .click() trigger.  See: https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#click
